# LibUsbDotNet USBEndpointReader DataReceived event is not firing when I expect it to

Tags: c#, .net, usb, libusbdotnet

I have a USB device from which I need to read data via LibUsbDotNet.

If I use the following code after I've successfully opened the device...

```
    protected UsbEndpointReader _libUsbReader = null;
    protected UsbEndpointWriter _libUsbWriter = null;
```

.

```
        IUsbDevice wholeUsbDevice = PhysicalLibUSBDevice as IUsbDevice;
        if (!ReferenceEquals(wholeUsbDevice, null))
        {
            // This is a "whole" USB device. Before it can be used, 
            // the desired configuration and interface must be selected.

            // Select config #1
            wholeUsbDevice.SetConfiguration(1);

            // Claim interface #0.
            wholeUsbDevice.ClaimInterface(0);
        }


        // Create the reader and writer streams
        _libUsbReader = PhysicalLibUSBDevice.OpenEndpointReader(LibUsbDotNet.Main.ReadEndpointID.Ep01);
        _libUsbWriter = PhysicalLibUSBDevice.OpenEndpointWriter(LibUsbDotNet.Main.WriteEndpointID.Ep02);

        _libUsbReader.DataReceivedEnabled = true;
        _libUsbReader.DataReceived += OnDataReceived;
        _libUsbReader.ReadThreadPriority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Highest;
        _libUsbReader.ReadBufferSize = 32;
```

and define the method:

```
    private void OnDataReceived(object sender, EndpointDataEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Data received");
    }
```

The event never fires.  I know the packets are being received by my code as I have a USB analyser attached and can see them coming in.

If I change the code to remove the reliance upon the event callback and instead use the loop below on a background thread to read the reader object

```
while(true)
{
     ErrorCode ec = ErrorCode.None;
     Thread.Sleep(5);
     int bytesRead;
     byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
     ec = _libUsbReader.Read(buffer, 1000, out bytesRead); 
     if(bytesRead>0) Console.WriteLine("Data Received");
}
```

Then everything works great.

I've tried playing around with the order I initialise, the values etc and can still get no joy.  Can anyone suggest why the events aren't firing if I use the DataReceived event?

I'm using LibUsbDotNet 2.2.8.

Comment: The event can fire, but not every time, 1 of 3 times in my tryout.
And your while(true) codes save me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but in your code:

```
...
_libUsbReader.DataReceivedEnabled = true;
_libUsbReader.DataReceived += OnDataReceived;
_libUsbReader.ReadThreadPriority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Highest;
_libUsbReader.ReadBufferSize = 32;
...
```

I have `DataReceivedEnabled` set after `DataReceived` (not sure if this makes a difference).

Also, I do not change thread priority and `ReadBufferSize`. The latter is 4096 by default. When data arrives, the `EndpointDataEventArgs` parameter to the event has the `Count` property with the actual number of bytes received.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

When opening the endpoint for reading, you should define the endpoint type to `interrupt`, otherwise the `Datarecieve` event won't fire.
(Optionally define the size of the read buffer)

In your code you'll have to modify just this row:

```
_libUsbReader = PhysicalLibUSBDevice.OpenEndpointReader(LibUsbDotNet.Main.ReadEndpointID.Ep01, 64, EndpointType.Interrupt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:

```
_libUsbReader.DataReceived += mEp_DataReceived;

private void mEp_DataReceived(object sender, EndpointDataEventArgs e) 
{
    try
    {
        Invoke(new OnDataReceivedDelegate(OnDataReceived), new object[] { sender, e });
    }
    catch
    {
        closeDevice();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the sollution is that you should read the endpoint content at the event (or discard it). I had the same problem, when only printing at the console the message I only entered 1 time. When I process in the event the data on the endpoint with read command, the problem seems to be solved.